# fopen the same file with apache and crontab - permission denied

Tags: php, fopen, cron, chmod, chown

i have this problem with fopen files. Maybe someone has a solution...

When fopen creates a file via the browser, the file is owned by "nobody", if i run the same script via crontab i get permission denied.
When the file is created by crontab, its owned by my cpanel username and then i cant fopen it via the web browser.

So the problem is that each of the methods used is using a different user to own the files created. How can i go around this? I searched how to run crontab as nobody but you have to be root and it seems complicated. I didnt find anything about running my web pages as my cpanel user. My php script has chmod 777 and the folder where the files are also have 777 just be be sure.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `chmod 777` is evil, don't do that, there is always some other way

Comment: indeed, just for testing sakes and the folder is password protected anyway.

Comment: Hmm well the php script does not need to have `0777` but the file that needs to be written must have `0777` if it needs to be writeable by two different users. Otherwise you must do something with ACL's but ACL's might be not supported by your server.

Comment: i will try to make fopen create files with 777 then

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a sysadmin guru, but if you have access to the server you can try this

1. Create a new group called "webwriters" and add nobody and yourself to that group
2. "chmod g+s webwriters" on the directory you write files
3. "chmod 660" each file so that the owner and the group have write privileges

If you don't have access to the server it's trickier, but solvable. Instead of running the script directly by cron, run the script on the web server itself by downloading the web page using "wget" or alternatively a php script calling "file_get_contents" on an URL. This assumes that the server is not locked down too tight...